# Avoid getting location twice

Tags: android, location, viewmodel

I need location in a Jetpack Compose app with two viewmodels. Viewmodel_A gets the location but the location is also needed later in viewmodel_B.
How can I pass the location from viewmodel_A to viewmodel_B or somehow avoid getting location twice. Any suggestion appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a shared ViewModel across fragments If you are using fragments or use a ViewModel on the Navgraph if you are using activities you can pass geolocation between activities through bundle and pass the geolocation to ViewModel_B as a nullable parameter if you did not fetch it at ViewModel_A then the ViewModelB should fetch it otherwise it is available and use it
you can also make a parent class of both view models to share the geolocation fetching code so you do not repeat the code in two classes

you can find related resources below

https://developer.android.com/codelabs/basic-android-kotlin-training-shared-viewmodel#0

https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-programmatic#share_ui-related_data_between_destinations_with_viewmodel

Comment: Thanks for the response. Both view models need the location in order to get data so only your last suggestions seems plausible. Would that parent class be another view model? Could you  please elaborate?

Comment: lets say you want to create Viewmodel_A and ViewModel_B they will have a parent ViewModel lets call it ViewModel_C  so  the class hierarchy would be like that 

                ViewModel()
                        ↓
               ViewModel_C()
                     ↙ ↘
ViewModel_A  ViewModel_B

where viewModels "A" and "B" shares "C"'s Code and C shares the ViewModel code

Comment: @sigjak if you found my answer helpful please can you make it accepted answer?